# Magento pass billing and shipping info to Sagepay module from IWD cart

Tags: magento, opayo

I am using Magento 1.7 with IWD onepage checkout with sagepay payment module.
(http://www.interiorwebdesign.com/magento/magento-one-step-checkout-module.html & http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-sage-pay-suite-ce-sage-pay-approved.html)

The sagepay module works fine with the standard checkout, but with the onepage checkout the shipping and billing do not pass and there is a enter shipping info error, or enter billing info.

The validation script looks for shipping 1st, so shipping is the 1st error.  Shipping can get passed by unchecking ship to this address, and rechecking it.  Then there is an error enter billing address.

The billing address gets passed if the page loads with the fields already filled, from the cache etc.

So it seems that the data can get passed, if it is there in the right order/time.

Is there some code I add that would duplicate the check/uncheck ship to this address or some code to pass the billing info?  What would the best place to out the code?

Answer (score 0):

find the checkout button and add:

```
billing.save();
```

to

```
onclick="checkout.save(); return false;"
```

to get

```
onclick="billing.save(); checkout.save(); return false;"
```